# How can I prevent a directory from being removed in rsync

Tags: linux, bash, shell, backup, rsync

I am trying to make a script for backing up my home and other important directories to an external drive, while excluding certain directories and filetypes (`--exclude`). Excluded files need to be deleted on the backup as well, in case I add a filetype or directory to the exclude list (`--delete-excluded`).

Also, everything that is removed needs to be backed up as well, in case something goes horribly wrong (`--backup --backup-dir=rsync/backup`).

I am starting out with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PATH_PWD="`pwd`"
PATH_HOME=~
SRC="/home/redsandro"
PATH_TARGET="/media/redsandro/MyBook 4TB/backup/`hostname`"
PATH_BIN="${SRC}/bin"
EXCL_FROM="${PATH_BIN}/rs-backup-external.sh.exclude.txt"
DATE="`date +%Y-%m-%d`"

OPTS="-ahl --update --del --delete-excluded --force --ignore-errors --progress --stats --exclude-from=$EXCL_FROM --log-file=~/rsync/rsync.$DATE.log"
OPTS="$OPTS --backup --backup-dir=rsync/backup/${DATE}"
#OPTS="$OPTS --dry-run"

echo Backing up $SRC to $PATH_TARGET...
echo  
sudo rsync $OPTS "$SRC/" "${PATH_TARGET}${SRC}"
```

Now, obviously, `--del` conflicts with `--backup --backup-dir=rsync/backup`. Can I exclude this directory from being deleted? Or is there perhaps an easier way to do this?

My goal is to have a script that I can run on all my machines, where a part syncs to a computer-specific directory, and another part (documents, pictures) sync to a global directory because they all need to be the same anyway.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm not clear what you are trying to do - a backup of a backup?

Comment: No I never did. I was trying to make a regular mirror backup, but also move all files that would be deleted in the backup to a special directory so I could undo anything that was removed by accident.

Comment: Perhaps look into using the -n or --dry-run option of rsync to see what it would do and then copy the data that would be deleted in the real run of rsync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync is an awesome tool, but sometimes difficult to use.

The problem is you're using `--exclude-from`, which sets global exclude rules to both the sending and receiving side.

Before rsync performs operations on the filesystem, it will first assemble two lists of files, one for the sending side (client) and other for the receiving side (server). If a file is excluded from both sides, rsync will simply ignore it. If it is excluded only from the sending side and exists on the receiving side, rsync will delete it.

In your case, since your rules are excluding files from both sides, rsync will not delete them. You then use `--delete-excluded` to force deletion. But, like you said, this option conflicts with `--backup --backup-dir=rsync/backup`.

I suggest you do the following.

1. Convert `$EXCL_FROM` to a normal filter file, i.e., insert the minus sign before each line to make them exclude rules.
2. Remove `--exclude-from=$EXCL_FROM` and `--delete-excluded` from the rsync options.
3. Include `-FF` on the rsync options.
4. Include the following command before the call to rsync.

   ```
   cp "$EXCL_FROM" "$SRC/.rsync-filter"
   ```

In this way, your rules will only apply to the sending side, and files specified as exclude rules will be removed from the receiving side if found. This should not conflict with backup options.

**Update**

Essentially, the `-FF` option is making rsync process per-directory filter files named `.rysnc-filter` in both sides of the transfer. In your case it will exist only on the sending side, so its rules won't apply to the receiving side.

Actually, `-FF` equals to `-F -F`. The first `F` tells rsync to merge rules from `.rsync-filter` in the root of the source and destination directories, like I said before. The second `F` tells rsync to exclude them. You don't want `.rsync-filter` being transferred, otherwise your exclude rules would also apply to the receiving side and your original problem would return – the excluded files would cease to be deleted.

Here's what my `man (1) rsync` says:

```
-F    same as --filter='dir-merge /.rsync-filter'
      repeated: --filter='- .rsync-filter'
```

Comment: I updated the answer with clarification about `-FF`. Feel free to ask if it's not clear.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a list format summary (pending peer review) and accepted your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, it seems that you voted the answer up, but did not accept it.

Comment: Huh? I remember accepting, and editing in the list format. Which is gone now too. Did Stack Overflow just go back in time a bit? This list summary was really helpful in conjunction with this answer, but I don't feel like going through the manual again. I'll accept your answer again though. :)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to locate your `--backup-dir` outside of your backup folder using absolute paths (specified with `../`).

ie. `--backup-dir="../rsync/backup/${DATE}"`

This will create a new folder at the same level as your destination folder. For example, if you were exporting to `/home/user/rsync/backup` the above command would store your deleted files at `home/user/rsync/rsync/backup/${DATE}`